Matrix parent-child transformation for 2D positioning
I am working with matrix math for parent / child transformations. I have to modify existing calculations to keep child scale constant while also keeping child position relative to its parent.
Here's some info about what I am given:
Input
Appends two matrices. AB = A * B
a - The local (child) matrix.
b - The world (parent) matrix.
Matrix
A matrix has of the following properties:
a - x scale
b - y skew
c - x skew
d - y scale
tx - x translation
ty - y translation
Working Calculations
This is the calculation that scales the child correctly based on parent resize:
a.a = (a.a * b.a) + (a.b * b.c)
This transfroms the child's x position correctly when the parent's x position changes:
a.tx = (a.tx * b.a) + b.tx
My goal
I want to keep the child's size constant, while still keeping it positioned based on the parent. When I try to change the transformation equation (a.tx), I get undesired results. I will post them below.
(To keep the child's scale the same I just set a.a = a.a)
This is the original parent/child setup. The parent is black, the children are all white
This is what I don't want. Here we keep the children at a constant scale, but when we shrink the parent, the children are offset from their original values
What is the correct equation to set a.tx to? I have tried a.tx = (a.tx + b.tx), but what didn't work either.
